# How can I use StoredContact.SetDisplayPictureAsync(IInputStream stream) in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8

See my code below, how can I tranfer a IsolatedStorageFileStream-obj to a IInputStream-obj? Thanks!

```
using(IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = 
   IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication().OpenFile(".."), FileMode.Open))
{
    await storedContact.SetDisplayPictureAsync(stream); // compile error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On WP8:

```
using System.IO;

using(IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication().OpenFile("..", FileMode.Open))
    await storedContact.SetDisplayPictureAsync(stream.AsInputStream());
```